# Custom IP protocol with ACK

Tags: python, networking, ip, scapy

I would like to explorer the possibilites of creating a custom IP procotol.
Perhaps with `scapy` in Python.

I've got a `tunnel` where I receive all `packet`s, so would like to see if I can dismiss destination IP, ports etc. and keep an absolut minimum - but with `ACK`.

Anyway this is possible with `scapy` or similar?

I've tried some simple stuff like:

```
p = IP(dst="192.168.0.2")/"My payload"
```

But it seems not doable in that manner.

Comment: "_see if I can dismiss destination IP, ports etc._" How do you expect that a packet can be delivered to the destination if the packet does not have a destination address? Also, the use of acknowledgements requires the packet to have a source address so that the acknowledgement can be sent back to the source.

Comment: When I have 2 servers with a tunnel between - I would like to explore/learn if it's possible to reduce overhead to a complete minimum when sending packets between them.

Comment: My question stands. A tunnel is simply a virtual interface, rather than a physical interface. You still need to route the packet to the correct interface based on a destination address, and you need a source address in order to be able to return traffic to the original source.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Forgoing transport layer port numbers limits communication to a single process on each node.

You'll need to register a protocol (number) with the IP stack to make it pass everything with that protocol to your handler. Most often, it's much easier to use UDP transport and build your own stuff on top. You can also simply number your UDP datagrams and ACK them on the application level.

Comment: I would like to explore if it's possible to only send ex. 50 bytes without any overhead at all - when I have a tunnel between to servers.
So each server would listen to a socket and print out all incoming packets/bytes.

Comment: "without any overhead at all" isn't possible. Even a simple serial cable requires start and stop bits... You seem to be forgetting Ethernet and IP overhead. UDP overhead just adds 8 bytes and you can't really go with much less...